# Error SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in asp.net application as following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[step2-e]
    @PI varchar(50),
    @Balance int output ,
    @Shipment_status varchar(50) output,
    @ETA varchar(50) output,
    @Forwarder varchar(50) output,
    @Transit_time Time output,
    @Shipping_date date output,
    @Shipping_method varchar(50) output,
    @Clearance_location varchar(50) output,
    @Advance_payment varchar(50) output 
    @Balance_t varchar(50) output,
    @Loading_date date output 
    @Balance_d date output
AS
Begin
   select 
       @Advance_payment = [advance_payment] @Balance = [Balance], 
       @Shipment_status = [Shipment_status],
       @ETA = [Eta], @Forwarder = [Forwarder], 
       @Transit_time = [Transit_time], @Shipping_date = [Shipping_date],
       @Shipping_method = [Shipping_method], 
       @Clearance_location = [Clearance_location],   
       @Balance_d = [Balance_due_d], 
       @Balance_t = [Balance_due_t], 
       @Loading_date = [Loading_date]  
   from 
       Inbound 
   where 
       [Pi1] =  @PI
End
GO

Select convert(date, [dbo].[step2-e] ,3);
GO
```

But I get error message after Go word on select says:-

> Error SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context

Ok I think there is problem of use Go word
When I searched I found solution but in asp.net website not asp.net application.
I found the solution [here](http://arcanecode.com/2013/03/28/ssdt-error-sql70001-this-statement-is-not-recognized-in-this-context/) but I can't find script file in asp.net application.
Just I can find it in asp.net website. What can I do ?

Comment: You can't use the result of SP in `CONVERT`.

Comment: Where do you have this SQL and how do you try to execute it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you posted it, there's a comma missing between the first two elements in your `SELECT`:

```
select 
    @Advance_payment = [advance_payment] @Balance = [Balance], 
                                       ^^^^
                                        | 
                                      here there should be a comma!
```

So try this instead:

```
select 
   @Advance_payment = [advance_payment],
   @Balance = [Balance], 
   ..... (rest of your statement) ....
```

Comment: marc i need to talk with you regarding this stored procedure

Answer (score 143):

This error is due to the fact that Build Action is set To Build inside the Properties. Set it to None and it should work fine. [image]

Comment: I have the same error message, but I need the build action to be `Build` so that Visual Studio runs the code when I run a publish profile. If I set it to `None` then it won't run my code. Visual Studio is having an issue with my `DROP PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: For my situation, there is no any .sql file inside my asp.net project. Where to find it?

Comment: @JohnLee I believe you ought to add it first. Otherwise, I don't see how you can check to see if it's working or not. Now, how you should add it, I believe it's beyond the scope of the problem addressed here.

Comment: @JoshWithee Did you got solution of your problem, i have exactly same issue, i need to deploy my .dacpac file into my sql datawarehosue. If i set build action "none" than .dacpac will not have anything.

Comment: Setting the Build Action to "None" is what we needed.  My employer uses SQL Projects to store Scripts and it has nothing to do with our builds or deployments.  It makes sense to be able to search for a SQL Object in the entire Solution and find it used across all your Projects (including the Deployment Scripts where it may be referenced).  Note: If you have a bunch of files, it may be best to close the Project/Solution, and do a Find-Replace in Notepad++ on the Project File instead of using the VS GUI.

Comment: For anyone wanting to include scripts other than creation of metadata (like INSERTS), set the action to PostDeploy.

Comment: This is bad advice. It's perfectly plausible for a script to have a build action.

Answer (score 1):

Comma missing from various places. After output in variables declaration:-

@Advance_payment varchar(50) output

@Loading_date date output

And in the select statement after [advance_payment]:

@Advance_payment = [advance_payment]